What is the correct tense: present perfect or simple past?
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) Over the past three days, it rained hard. This morning, it was sunny. However, it is snowing tonight.
(1b) Over the past three days, it has rained hard. This morning, it was sunny. However, it is snowing tonight.
Which tense of "rain" fits the context better? Thanks.
